# Issue with parsing time string timezone to timestamp in oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have a date string like `Mon Jun 24 23:42:36 EDT 2019`, which I want to obtain a timestamp out of it in my oracle sql query. For that I am trying below query

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('Mon Jun 24 23:42:36 EDT 2019', 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY')  as "Creation Time"
from dual;
```

This is giving me error as 'timezone region not found'. I tried TZD as well for timezone parsing but its not helping.

What is the right date format to parse the give string to timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timezone `EDT` is not a valid time zone. Check valid time zone names with this query:

```
SELECT tzname, tzabbrev, TZ_OFFSET(tzname)
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES 
WHERE tzabbrev = 'EDT' OR tzname = 'EDT';


+-------------------------------------------------------+
|TZNAME                      |TZABBREV|TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|America/Detroit             |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Fort_Wayne          |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Grand_Turk          |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Indiana/Indianapolis|EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Indiana/Marengo     |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Indiana/Petersburg  |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Indiana/Vevay       |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Indiana/Vincennes   |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Indiana/Winamac     |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Indianapolis        |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Iqaluit             |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Kentucky/Louisville |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Kentucky/Monticello |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Louisville          |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Montreal            |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Nassau              |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/New_York            |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Nipigon             |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Pangnirtung         |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Santo_Domingo       |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Thunder_Bay         |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Toronto             |EDT     |-04:00           |
|Canada/Eastern              |EDT     |-04:00           |
|EST5EDT                     |EDT     |-04:00           |
|US/East-Indiana             |EDT     |-04:00           |
|US/Eastern                  |EDT     |-04:00           |
|US/Michigan                 |EDT     |-04:00           |
|America/Cancun              |EDT     |-05:00           |
|America/Indiana/Tell_City   |EDT     |-05:00           |
|America/Jamaica             |EDT     |-05:00           |
|America/Port-au-Prince      |EDT     |-05:00           |
|Jamaica                     |EDT     |-05:00           |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

For example this one is working:

```
select 
   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('Mon Jun 24 23:42:36 America/New_York 2019', 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY')  as "Creation Time"
from dual;
```

Format `TZD` is used to determine daylight-saving times, for example `2019-11-03 01:40:00` is ambiguous, see

```
ALTER SESSION SET ERROR_ON_OVERLAP_TIME = TRUE; -- default is FALSE

SELECT 
   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('Sun Nov 03 01:42:36 America/New_York 2019', 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY')  AS "Creation Time"
FROM dual;

Error at line 2
ORA-01883: overlap was disabled during a region transition


SELECT 
   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('Sun Nov 03 01:42:36 America/New_York EST 2019', 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZR TZD YYYY')  AS "Creation Time A",
   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('Sun Nov 03 01:42:36 America/New_York EDT 2019', 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZR TZD YYYY')  AS "Creation Time B"
FROM dual;

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Creation Time A                     |Creation Time B                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|03.11.2019 01:42:36.000000000 -05:00|03.11.2019 01:42:36.000000000 -04:00|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: No, `EDT` is ambiguous. There are a few exceptions you can use, check with `SELECT tzname, tzabbrev FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES WHERE tzname = tzabbrev;`